# http post response is null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-mvc, rx-java

I'm sending http post request to REST api, I'm getting status ok response from server but in this script, it  always runs 'myError' function. In backend everything is running fine without any error. In error function also response value remains undefined.

```
var toDoApp = angular.module('toDoApp');

toDoApp.factory('registrationService', function() {
var register = {};

register.registeruser = function(user, $http) {
    $http({
        method : "POST",
        url : 'register',
        data : user
    }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
        console.log("success");
    }, function myError(response) {
        console.log("error");           
    });

}

return register;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Inject the `http` service to the factory. Not the `registeruser` function.

```
toDoApp.factory('registrationService', function($http) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Do some needful correction.

```
var toDoApp = angular.module('toDoApp',[]);

toDoApp.factory('registrationService', function($http) {
var register = {};

register.registeruser = function(user) {
    $http({
        method : "POST",
        url : 'register',
        data : user
    }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
        console.log("success");
    }, function myError(response) {
        console.log("error");           
    });

}

return register;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is showing because you did not inject `$http` service to to your `toDoAppfactory` not in your `registeruser` function . You should inject `$http` service to your factory. like :

```
toDoApp.factory('registrationService', function($http)
```

And your function `registeruser` should be like

```
register.registeruser = function(user) {
    $http({
        method : "POST",
        url : 'register',
        data : user
    }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
        console.log("success");
    }, function myError(response) {
        console.log("error");           
    });

}
```